# Translating ObjC return type (id<protocol>) to its Swift 3.0 equivalent

Tags: objective-c, swift3, protocols, return-type

I'm getting a bit confused on how to translate an Objective-C method signature into its Swift 3.0 equivalent.

The following is the original Objective-C method using the return type of 'id' with its UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol:

**Objective-C**

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed
{
    return self;
}
```

I wish to translate the Objective-C version into its corresponding Swift 3.0 equivalent:

**Swift 3.0**

```
func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }
```

Is the Swift 3.0 version correct?

...or should I use the **AnyObject?** return type:

[image]

...from which I get the warning; and what about handling the (id) signature?

More specifically, should 'id' be translated to protocol? type?

Here's the compiler's "solution":
[image]

What's the correct format?

---

This is what the compiler returned:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the protocol name alone is the full type when translating `id<SomeProtocol>` from ObjC to Swift. (You don't need to translate anything about the thing conforming to the protocol being `id`. The protocol comes in from ObjC, so the only things that can conform to it are objects — that is, your protocol is implicitly a subtype of `AnyObject`.)

In your case, `optional func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?` is also [the official translation of that delegate method signature](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate/1622047-animationcontroller).

Declaring your method as returning `AnyObject?` instead breaks the delegate method signature, which won't work right because it shares the same ObjC selector with the correct method. (And making the incorrect signature `@nonobjc` guarantees it won't be called.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on ricster's answer, I recheck my code.

I discovered that I didn't adopt the  protocol per stated Objective-C source in the host (self) and hence, got the Swift 3.0 compiler complaint:

[image]